# How to merge 2 object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby 1.8.7

```
@post = Post.find(1) + Post.find(2)
```

undefined method `+' for Post

```
@post = Post.find(1).merge(Post.find(2))
```

undefined method merge for Post

Comment: what should be in result?

Comment: 2 object in 1 variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
@posts = Post.find(1,2)
```

Plus, what I read from the comments, you want to merge `@posts` and `Post.all`, both of which are arrays, so you can simply use `+` to add them.

Beside that answer, I think you don't need to do `@posts` as you are doing `Post.all`.

As `@posts` is an array, you can simply merge two arrays:

```
@posts + Post.all
```

Or you can do:

```
@post | Post.all
```

Comment: is a fictional example, but when i use + ruby sey my undefined method `+' for #<Post:0x7f5fb3385918>

Comment: will you please check what you get when you do, @posts.class ?

Comment: logger.info @post.class - yes class Post

Comment: it meant that @post is type of Post not Array you have to convert it first into array, you can do as follow, `@post.to_a + Post.all` this will definitely work.

Comment: @posts = Post.find(1,2).to_a + Post.all.to_a

Comment: You don't need Post.all to convert to array as it would already given you array, plus Post.find(1, 2) also give you an array, as you are finding 2 different posts of different ids, you only need to do it if you are doing, Post.find(1), as it would give you an object of type Post, so we need to convert it into array

Answer (score 3):

pass the ids to `find` in a single call like

```
@posts = Post.find([1, 2])
```

Be warned that if there is no post with ID=1 or ID=2, this will raise an error.  If you dont this, use `where` or `find_all_by_id`

```
@posts = Post.where(id: [1, 2])
@posts = Post.find_all_by_id([1, 2])
```

The main difference between the 2 is that you can chain other queries with `where` whereas `find_all_by_id` already returns an array so you can't chain queries.

Comment: `@posts` in this answer and `Post.all` are both arrays so you should be able to just add them `@all_posts = @posts + Post.all`

Comment: undefined method `+' for #<Post:0x7f5fb3385918>

Comment: Just try to understand what is actually happing, what object is in which variable and what methods are available for what class and what instance of a class. An Array is a collection of objects wheres Post is an individual object. You cannot call + on the Post object you need to push it to the array with <<

Answer (score 2):

You can find array of projects just by appending the ids. So in your case it will be

`@posts = Post.find(1,2)`

Comment: First of all your `@posts` object is not an array and this could be due to only one id being passed into `Post.find(..)`. You can do `[Post.find(1,2)]` to get array always irrespective of number of ids and then add it with Post.all. In any case you should not be doing this as this will obviously lead to duplicate objects in the array

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
@posts = []
@posts << Post.find(1)
@posts << Post.find(2)
```

And keep adding:

```
@posts << Post.find_all_by_id([5, 6])
```

Or even:

```
@posts << Post.all
```

Comment: cool, but i now can not map for @post, error: undefined method `name' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x7f5fb3570700> when i call options_for_select(@post).map{|m| [m.name, m.id]}

Comment: You want `@posts.concat` for collections. `<<` will just push an array into the existing array which probably isn't what you want, you'd have to flatten it at a later time

Comment: undefined method `concat' for #<Post:0x7f5fb351ada0>